# linear space and linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n$ and $f$ be linear functionals on a finite dimensional linear space $E$ over the field $K$. Let
$$N=\{x:f_1(x)=f_2(x)=\cdots=f_n(x)=0\}$$
Then I need to show that (b) implies (a).

(a) There exists scalar $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ such that
$f= c_1f_1 + c_2f_2 +\dots+ c_n  f_n$.

(b) $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in N$.

In fact both are equivalent. I have been able to show (a) implies (b), but how do I show (b) implies (a).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are at least $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n$ a basis for $E^*$?

Comment: No such infirmation given.

Comment: Then the statement is false. Take $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^n\subset\mathbb R^{n+1}$ as $f_i=(0,0,\dots, 1, \dots 0)$ (1 only in the $i$-th place) and set $x=(0,0,\dots,0,1)\in\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Then $f_i(x)=0$ for all $i=1,\dots, n$), but $f(x)=1$ for $f=(0,0,\dots,1)$. (I'm identifying $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$.

Comment: I am sorry that I missed to mention that E is n dimensional

Answer (score 1):

Choose a linear independent subset of $f_1,\dots,f_n$ (say $f_1,\dots,f_k$) and complete it to a basis (say $f_1,\dots,f_k,g_1,\dots,g_l$). Find a dual basis $e_1,\dots,e_{k+l}$ of $E$. Then $c_i=f(e_i)$. (Show that $e_{k+j}\in N$ for all $j\in\{1,\dots, l\}$.)

Comment: Who is $f$ in your answer?

Comment: Well, $f$ is given. One is supposed to prove that for any $f\in E^*$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in N$, $f$ is a linear combination of $f_1,\dots,f_n$.

Comment: With some changes even for infinite dimensional. It is actually not necessary to complete the functionals to a basis. Let $M$ be a complement of $N$. Then $f_1,\dots,f_k$ restricted on $M$ form a basis of $M^*$. Again, we can construct a dual basis $e_1,\dots,e_k$ on $M$. Then every element $x\in E$ can be written as a linear combination of this basis and some element in $N$. Now, it suffices to express $f(x)$, while we can again denote $c_i:=f(e_i)$.

Comment: Yes you're right. I misunderstood the question. Im sorry.